# Python Recursive Power

Tags: math, recursion, exponent

```
def main():

    base = input('Please Enter An Integer for the Base: ')
    exponent = input ('Please Enter An Exponent: ')

def power (base, exponent):
    if exponent == 0:
        return base
    else :
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
    

main()
```

SAMPLE OUT:

```
Enter an integer for the base: 2
Enter an integer for the exponent: 5
2 to the power 5 equals 32
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I was wondering how to print out the answer "2 to the power of 5 equal 32" Sorry new to posting something...

Comment: You have a bug in your `power` function.  Think about what your function would return if you had `exponent == 0` and `base == 5`. Now think about what the function _should_ return.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Python 3, use string formatting like this:

```
result = power(base, exponent)
print("{} to the power of {} equals {}".format(base, exponent, result))
```

In Python 2,

```
print "%d to the power of %d equals %d" % (base, exponent, result)
```

Comment: def main():

    base = input('Please Enter An Integer for the Base: ')
    exponent = input ('Please Enter An Exponent: ')
      
   
    
def power (base, exponent):
           
    if exponent == 1:
           
        return base
           
    else :
           
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
    
    result = power(base, exponent)
    
    print("{} to the power of {} equals {}".format(base, exponent, result)) 
main() .... When I tried to run the program it doesn't show the results

Comment: You have your code in the wrong order. The `print` statement, and the calculation of the result, should be part of the `main` function, which comes before the definition of the `power` function.

Comment: I've added the result into the main function and I'm able to enter the integer and the exponent but as the program is running i keep on getting this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: This is likely a problem with the types returned by the `input()` method. You must learn to diagnose and fix your own error messages!

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of working for me, but I get 1000 if I use 10 as base and 2 as the exponent. Trying to figure it out now why the math is wrong.

```
def main():

   base = float(input('Please Enter An Integer for the Base: '))
   exponent = float(input('Please Enter An Exponent: '))
   result = power(base, exponent)
   print("{} to the power of {} equals {}".format(base, exponent, result))

def power (base, exponent):

   if exponent == 0:
      return base
   else :
      return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
main()
```